# Return results where no values exist for a specific column

Tags: mysql, not-exists

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated please.

Aim of the statement is to read the East (x) and West (y) in the same row for the same year and month. 
Not sure if I am over complicating things. I am stuck with the y as part of my statement. Currently there are no records for statement WHERE Dam_Name = 15 AND [Survey_Date] > DATEADD(yyyy,-1,getdate()) so my final results return no records.

How do I get it to still give me the list with the x values and blank for the y values?

Here is what I built.

```
  ;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT [Survey_Year], [Water_Volume], DateName(month,DateAdd(month,Survey_Month,-1)) as Month
    FROM Dam_Water_Levels
    WHERE Dam_Name = 14 AND [Survey_Date] > DATEADD(yyyy,-1,getdate())
)


, y AS
(
  SELECT 
    Case when count (1) >0 
        then (select [Survey_Year], [Water_Volume], DateName(month,DateAdd(month,Survey_Month,-1))) 
        else '' 
    END 
    as Month
    FROM Dam_Water_Levels
    WHERE Dam_Name = 15 AND [Survey_Date] > DATEADD(yyyy,-1,getdate())
    Group by Survey_Year,Survey_Month,  Water_Volume
)


SELECT Month = x.Month,  East = x.Water_Volume, West = y.Water_Volume
FROM x 
    INNER JOIN y ON x.Month = y.Month
    inner join Months mon on mon.Month=y.Month
order by y.Survey_Year, mon.ID;
```

Hope it makes sense

Regards,
Tanya

Comment: You need LEFT JOIN (if the record may absent from one side only) or FULL JOIN (if it may absent from any side). But FULL JOIN is not supported in MySQL, it must be emulated by UNION.

Comment: For detail OP, just replace "INNER JOIN y" with "LEFT OUTER JOIN y" and it'll do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Another way I looked at it was to use this query. The down side was I had to include a column I didn't want (Intended_Month) because I needed it in my order by statement.

SELECT
    Distinct a.Intended_Month as ' ', DateName(month,DateAdd(month,a.Intended_Month,-1)) as Month, 
    ( SELECT Water_Volume from Dam_Water_Levels as y WHERE a.Survey_Year=y.Survey_Year and a.Survey_Month=y.Intended_Month and y.Dam_Name = 14) as 'East'   ,
     (SELECT Water_Volume from Dam_Water_Levels as x WHERE a.Survey_Year=x.Survey_Year and a.Survey_Month=x.Intended_Month and x.Dam_Name = 15) as' West'
 FROM Dam_Water_Levels as a

where a.[Survey_Date] > DATEADD(yyyy,-1,getdate())
order by a.Intended_Month